# Dropping columns using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data-frame with these columns:

```
[QWE_234, QWE_789234, QWE_2_234, QWE_2_789234 ...]
```

I want to exclude those with double underscore.
I.e., to remain with only:

```
[QWE_234, QWE_789234 ...]
```

**Note: I have other columns with double underscore, so I want to exclude only the "QWE" columns containing underscore.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `filter` with `regex` with a list comp.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"QWE_234": 0, "QWE_789234": 0, "QWE_2_234": 0, "QWE_2_789234": 0}, index=[0]
)

  QWE_234  QWE_789234  QWE_2_234  QWE_2_789234
0        0           0          0             0

cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in df.filter(regex='\w+_\w+_').columns]

print(df[cols])

   QWE_234  QWE_789234
0        0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do without `regex`:

```
mask = df.columns.str.startswith('QWE_')
df = df.loc[:, ~mask]
```

Or similarly:

```
drop_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('QWE_')]
df = df.drop(drop_cols, axis=1)
```